# LLVM IR string literal in multiple lines

Tags: string, clang, llvm, literals

I am emitting LLVM IR by myself.

Let's say we have a string literal with the length of 400 characters.
Are there anyways that I could emit the string literal in multiple lines?

Here is an example:

```
@.str = internal global [400 x i8] c"the-first-100-characters"
"the-second-100-characters"
"the-third-100-characters"
"the-fourth-100-characters", align 1
```

Clang does not accept the above IR where multiple lines of string literals are concatenated together.

Here is the error message:

```
error: constant expression type mismatch
```

Once I put them all together in a "all-400-characters" string, it works.

The purpose is to convert my own language into LLVM IR.
Previously, my own language was converted into C/C++, which works very well.

Comment: Please format code as code (not as normal text).

Comment: What are you aiming to do with this? What's causing the problem ATM?

Comment: Just updated the content based on the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you emit textual LLVM IR and not using C++ API?

Comment: I could emit the bitcode LLVM IR; but for now, we are trying to emit the textual format. When you mention about using C++ API, are you saying call C++ APIs to emit IR? we  emit the IR via Java by ourselves.

Comment: As far as the static declaration of strings there is no multi-line layout support in the IR. You''l have to make it one string.

Comment: @dac I'm not sure I understand the requirement; Why do you need to split it into multiple lines? Is it for prettifying purposes because otherwise, it doesn't make any difference. There's no multiline support for constant strings like that in IR.